# Multiple JTables with dynamic names

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm working on my first java program. I'm making a Project Manager program.

The base idea is that i have a `JList` which contains the names of the Co-workers. If you double click one of the names a `JTabbedPane` will pop up a new tab and will be populated a `JTable` what is containing the specific persons tasks.

And here comes the tricky part. I want to use this `JTable` to modify the datas so i need to give a specific name to the `JTable` so i can use that later on in my methods to call it.

The question is how can i create dynamic names to these tables so i can call it later (something like this: table+tabID).

OR

Is there a better solution to my problem?

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The solution was:

I made an `ArrayList<JTables>` to store the tables and I'm using the tab indexes to get the proper table.